# Store order_discount Not Showing In Next Step

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, checkout

Using store, I am creating a multi-step checkout process. The first form is displaying the products in the cart page, second is shipping details form and third is my credit card/payment page.

On my first form the user is allowed to enter a promo code. This refresh the page and displays the `order_discount` correctly, but when going to the next step, it seems as if the `order_discount` tag resets to R0.00. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser's developer tools network tab to see exactly which fields are being submitted.

My guess is that when the customer clicks through to the next step of the checkout, you are either submitting two `promo_code` fields, or submitting a blank `promo_code` field (which would reset the discount back to $0).